# Verify string exists as key or value in Python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm building a scraper/crawler for linux directories. in essence the program will take users input for a file type to scrape for 
(which is where my question comes in)

I'm storing acceptable file extension types in a dictionary w/ nested lists for example:

```
file_types = {'images': ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp'], 'text': ['txt', 'doc', 'pdf']}
```

To give the user which options they have to choose from I use this for loop:

```
for k, v in file_types.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Which prints the dictionary in this format:

```
audio ['mp3', 'mpa', 'wpi', 'wav', 'wpi']

text ['txt', 'doc', 'pdf']

video ['mp4', 'avi', '3g2', '3gp', 'mkv', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mpg', 'wmv', 'flv']

images ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp']
```

Now if I do:

`scrape_for = input("Please enter either the type of file, or the 
extension you would like to scrape for: \n")`

how can I validate the users input exists in my dictionary `file_types` as either a key OR a value (I say key OR value so if the user inputs 'images' I can use the values of the key images)

Comment: a not so pythonic approach: `key if key in file_types else reduce(lambda p,n: p or n if key in n else False, file_types.values(), False)`

Answer (score 3):

I'd first flatten the extensions list into a set so you don't have to loop through it later on and can do quick on-the-spot lookups:

```
file_types = {'images': ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp'], 'text': ['txt', 'doc', 'pdf']}
file_extensions = set(sum(file_types.values(), []))

scrape_for = input("Enter the type / extension to scrape: ").lower()
if scrape_for not in file_types and scrape_for not in file_extensions:
    print("I don't support this type / extension!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's cool list comprehension make a flat list of extensions

```
list_of_extensions = [ item \
    for extensionList in file_types.values() \
    for item in extensionList
]
```

Now use idiomatic Python construct `item in list_var`, which evaluates to True if the item is present in that list, and the `or`.

```
if scrape_for in file_types or scrape_for in list_of_extensions:
    # do something
else:
    print("Unsupported file type: " + scrape_for)
```

**Note:** using the `in` operator on dict name is equivalent (in effect) to `scrape_for in file_types.keys()`